# R: ggplot2 Change the margins of box around text in annotate(geom="label"...)

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

Is there a way to control the margin size of the box around the text ?

```
x <- data.frame(x = c(5, 10), y = c(0.5, 1))

ggplot(data=x, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill=c("red4","cornflowerblue"))+
  annotate(geom= "label", x=5, y=.6, label="Just\ntext\nhere\nwith\ndifferent\nmargins", size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Add the argument `label.padding = unit(0.5, "lines")` in your call to `annotate`. Check ggplot documentation for `geom_label` for further details and arguments to control the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the parameter `label.padding`. See [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html).

```
ggplot(data=x, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill=c("red4","cornflowerblue")) + 
  annotate(geom= "label", x=5, y=.6, 
           label="Just\ntext\nhere\nwith\ndifferent\nmargins", size=5,
           label.padding=unit(4, "lines"))    # <------------
```